# VBA - how to set empty cells in a range to zero

Tags: vba, excel-2016

I am still new to Visual Basic, and would like to create a macro that essentially fills in empty cells with a value (integer) of zero, while leaving existing cells in the range as they were (if not empty). My code currently is this:

```
 Sub FillEmptyCellsWithZeros()

'this should fill empty cells with a 0 value for the range selected



 Dim cell As Object
    Dim y As Integer

    y = 0
    For Each cell In Selection
      If y = Empty Then 
      Selection.Value = 0 
      ElseIf y <> Empty Then 
      Selection.Value = ActiveCell.Value 
      End If 
    Next cell

End Sub
```

I know that most likely my loop isn't doing anything in this piece of code, but I cannot seem to get the result and this code was the closest I got.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to take anything away from Scott's answer, but if you're interested in a non-looping answer, you can try something like:

```
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = 0
```

this may cause problems if you have a large selection with a lot of discontinuous ranges, but it should be pretty reliable.

Also, if you have a formula that returns a blank (e.g.):

```
=IF(E16="","")
```

it will not consider those as blank (meaning they will still "appear" blank after running the code), so your mileage may very.

Comment: A quick question as I do not use specialCells, will this also choose those cells that have a formula that returns a null string?

Comment: it will not overwrite formulas.  I'll update my answer to include that as well.

Comment: I was curious.  Again I do not use it very often.

Comment: @ScottCraner Nope, glad you asked...I don't use it enough to know the various nuances of SpecialCells.  Depending on the circumstances, this may be a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

You are over thinking a little:

```
 Sub FillEmptyCellsWithZeros()

'this should fill empty cells with a 0 value for the range selected



 Dim cell As Object
    Dim y As Integer

    y = 0
    For Each cell In Selection
      If cell = "" Then
        cell = y
      End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Scott. This worked perfectly. Still trying to learn the main syntax's and main objects of VBA.

Comment: @MikeMirabelli if this helped please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.